# Weird URL in minitest rail test case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

#### Look at this error:

```
AnswersControllerTest#test_should_destroy_answer [/Users/pitosalas/mydev/questionanswer/test/controllers/answers_controller_test.rb:47]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/questions/525858932> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/questions.525858932>.
Expected "http://www.example.com/questions/525858932" to be === "http://www.example.com/questions.525858932".
```

#### Notice the URL

In the error message from the test the url has a . in an incorrect place. This is telling me something but I am not sure what.

**http://www.example.com/questions.525858932**

#### Here is the test:

```
  test "should destroy answer" do
    assert_no_difference("Question.count") do
      delete question_answer_url(@question, @answer)
    end

    assert_redirected_to question_url(@question)
  end
```

#### And the controller:

```
  def destroy
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        if !@answer.comments.empty?
          redirect_to questions_url(@question), notice: "First delete all the comments"
        elsif @answer.destroy
          redirect_to questions_url(@question), notice: "Answer was successfully destroyed."
        else
          redirect_to questions_url(@question), notice: "Answer could not be destroyed."
        end
      end
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

#### Question

What does the dot in the url mean? I know there's a bug but,,,

Comment: Your controller redirects to `questions_url(@question)` (plural) your test is looking for `question_url(@question)` (singular). The dot is because the id is being interpreted as the format as in the route `"/questions(.:format)"`

Comment: Perfect, that was my problem. Thanks so much!